# マイクで入力した音声をリアルタイムで特徴量抽出したい

Tags: python

マイクで入力した音声をリアルタイムで特徴量抽出したいです。

pyaudioを用いてストリーミング入力しようとしていますが、HTKやtorchaudioなどのライブラリではwavファイルからloadしたもので抽出できるようになっています。

wavファイルを経由することなく特徴量抽出する方法はないでしょうか。

```
import pyaudio
P = pyaudio.PyAudio()
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024
stream = P.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, input=True, output=False)
while stream.is_active():
    input = stream.read(CHUNK)
    # filterbankなどの処理
```

Answer (score 2):

torchaudio v0.12 で追加された [torchaudio.io.StreamReader](https://pytorch.org/audio/0.12.0/io.html#streamreader) を使うと、マイクからの入力を直接 torch.Tensor で読み込むことができます。対応する FFmpeg ライブラリが必要になります。(conda を使っている場合は conda install 'ffmpeg<4.4' でインストールできます。)

参照：
https://pytorch.org/audio/stable/tutorials/device_asr.html

以下は macOS の場合の例です。

```py
# StreamReader の初期化
streamer = torchaudio.io.StreamReader(
    src=":default",  # デフォルトのオーディオ入力デバイスを使用。
    format = "avfoundation",  # デバイスドライバー
)

# オーディオの入力を設定
streamer.add_basic_audio_stream(
    frames_per_chunk=8000,  # 8000 フレームを一度に取得
    sample_rate=8000,  # 8k Hz にリサンプリング
)

# ストリーム
#
# timeout はオーディオデバイスが十分なデータを生成するまでの許容待ち時間で、
# -1 はデータが整うまで待機します。単位:秒
#
# backoff は待機許容時間内でリトライする間隔を指定します。単位:秒
for (audio_chunk, ) in streamer.stream(timeout=-1, backoff=1.0):
    # audio_chunk は 8000 フレームの torch.Tensor
    pass
```

`format` 引数に渡すデバイスドライバーは OS と FFmpeg ライブラリの種類によって異なりますが、 macOS では `"avfoundation"`, Windows では `"dshow"` が標準的です。

各ドライバーが扱えるデバイスの種類は `ffmpeg` コマンドで確認できます。

```
$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i dummy
...
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] [0] ZoomAudioDevice
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x126e049d0] [1] MacBook Pro Microphone
```

マイクを使ったデータの取得はタイミングが重要なので、サブプロセスを立ち上げてその中でストリーミングの for ループを回し続けると良いかと思います。